# efficient sort | uniq for the case of a large number of duplicates

Tags: linux, unix

**Summary** : is there a way to get the unique lines from a file and the number of occurrences more efficiently than using a `sort | uniq -c | sort -n`?

**Details**: I often pipe to `sort | uniq -c | sort -n` when doing log analysis to get a general trending of which log entries show up the most / least etc. This works most of the time - except when I'm dealing with a very large log file that ends up with a very large number of duplicates (in which case `sort | uniq -c` ends up taking a long time).

**Example**: The specific case I'm facing right now is for getting a trend from an 'un-parametrized' mysql bin log to find out which queries are run the most. For a file of a million entries which I pass through a grep/sed combination to remove parameters - resulting in about 150 unique lines  -  I spend about 3 seconds grepping & sedding, and about 15s sorting/uniq'ing.

Currently, I've settled with a simple c++ program that maintains a map of < line, count > - which does the job in less than a second - but I was wondering if an existing utility already exists.

Comment: Wait until your C++ program will run out of memory :-D

Comment: why would using a map to store the count of occurrences use up more memory than sorting every occurrence (i.e. the first sort in the sort | uniq -c | sort -n sequence)?

Comment: [GNU `sort`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) will use temporary files to hold data that is too large to fit into memory at once.

Comment: @ephemient: thanks, that pointed me in the direction of checking the version of coreutils.

Comment: this is the cpp implementation for reference [link](https://gist.github.com/2983201)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the performance difference will be, but you can replace the `sort | uniq -c` with a simple `awk` script. Since you have many duplicates and it hashes instead of sorting, I'd imagine it's faster:

```
 awk '{c[$0]++}END{for(l in c){print c[l], l}}' input.txt | sort -n
```

Comment: thanks , this works rather nicely for files which have a large number of dupes.
Turned out however, that the two systems I was testing on (Mac OSX Lion, and RHEL 4) had an insanely old version of sort (5.x)

comparing the performance with coreutils 8.x (tested on ubuntu 12.04) there is no problem, the sort, uniq, sort chain works like a charm.

Comment: comparison between coreutils 5.x and 8.x for those who are interested: [link](https://gist.github.com/2981363)

Comment: If you have a big directory of files you want to sort & uniq using this script, you can just run it like this:
`awk '{c[$0]++}END{for(l in c){print c[l], l}}' <(find . -type f | xargs cat) | sort -n`

Comment: Huge improvement when trying to find unique user agents in an Apache log.